# SQLAlchemy core + Pyramid not closing connections

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have **SQLAlchemy CORE 1.0.9** with Pyramid framework **1.7**. And I am using the following configuration for connecting to a postgres **9.4** database:

```python
# file __ini__.py
from .factories import root_factory
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application."""

    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=root_factory)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, prefix='sqlalchemy.')

    # Retrieves database connection
    def get_db(request):
        connection = engine.connect()
        def disconnect(request):
            connection.close()
        request.add_finished_callback(disconnect)
        return connection

    config.add_request_method(get_db, 'db', reify=True)
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

After a few hours using the app I start getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Apparently I have reached the maximum number of connections. It seems like **connections.close()** doesn't really close the connection, just returns the connection to the pool. I know I could use the **NullPool** to disable pooling but probably that will have a huge impact in the performance.

Does somebody know the right way to configure **SQLAlchemy Core** to get a good performance and close the connections properly?

Please abstain from sending links to [pyramid tutorials](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html#application-configuration-with-init-py). I am **NOT interested in SQLAlchemy ORM setups**. Only **SQLAlchemy Core** please.

Comment: I think you should use the Zope Transaction Manager (pyramid_tm). This is a wrapper around your Pyramid app that integrates with the request processing. It automatically commits the transaction if the request completes without incident; alternatively, if an exception arises, it will abort the transaction. [More Info](http://pyramid-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transactions.html)

Comment: FWIW I don't see anything wrong with your example code. The ORM has `Session.remove` to ensure things are really removed, but using SQLA core, the `.close` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything was fine in the previous setup. The problem was caused by Celery workers not closing connections.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with celery. How did you fix this? I'm running into this problem setting up [airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow) on GCP